# google sheet api events(onEdit, etc) c#

Tags: c#, google-sheets, events, google-api

I have a google sheet case in my project and I want from my application to listen for data change on spreadsheet changes and change it somewhere else.

Is it any way to do that with the official API of google?

Also, I see the below link and I think it's for javascript cases, is there any way to do this on c#?

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Comment: Check out [push](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/push) notifications in google drive

Comment: @DaImTo thanks for your comment, Is it work on google sheets too?

Comment: Push notifications will work with any file stored in Google drive.  Google sheets are stored in Google drive. So yes it will work with a sheet.

Answer (score 0):

To start with [Push notifications](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/push) , you will use the [Files: watch](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/watch) method to start watching for changes to a file.

Regarding your question, **is there any way to do this on c#?**
Yes and you can find an [example](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/quickstart/dotnet#step_1_prepare_the_project) of how to authenticate and authorize your app to make calls to the Drive API.